# EJS using fetched json data with d3 chart

Tags: javascript, express, d3.js, ejs

*New to express.

I have `index.ejs` and `script.js`.

My script fetches some JSON data from an api just fine.

```
const fetch = require("node-fetch");
const url = '...'

fetch (url)
    .then(response => {
        return response.json()
    })
    .then(data =>{
    console.log(data)
    })
    .catch(err => {
    })
```

How would I go about using this returned JSON data to create a chart in my index page with d3.

I have searched around but am still confused. Any advice would be super helpful! Thanks.

Comment: so express is your backend framework which is built in nodejs, so you need to send the response back to the UI. So you can use the data and create the d3 chart. Basically you need to create a rest service which can be consume from UI

Comment: Thanks for your advice! When you say I need to send the response back to the UI could you elaborate on that please.

Comment: response.send https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.send from your backend which means from express code

Comment: Thanks for the link. Just to clarify, do I need to fetch "then" res.send it? Just not sure how to structure it in the script. Send it to my server.js file?

Comment: from express js where do you get the data, from db or from another api

Comment: Oh I'm getting it from an API not a db.

Comment: okay so on the then block of data you can do res.send from the express code

Comment: Okay gotcha! Thanks alot. Big help!

Comment: Cool, i will add the discussed points as answer if it helped you kindly vote and accept it :)

Comment: @ john have added it kindly check it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So as discussed in the comments, the problem was having a server which is return in express framework of nodejs

So in express code need to call an api and get data, once we get the data we need to send it to the front end.

So for returning data to front end we can use [res.send](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.send) of express

```
const fetch = require("node-fetch");
const url = '...'

fetch (url)
    .then(response => {
        return response.json()
    })
    .then(data =>{
    console.log(data)
     res.send(data)
    })
    .catch(err => {
    })
```

And in the front end we need to access this api as shown below

```
const getData = async () => {
  try {
    const response = await fetch(url) // server url (express js route) example http://localhost:6000/api/getChartData
    if(response.ok){
      const  body = await response.json()
      console.log(body)
      // once you get the data you can create d3 chart
      return
    }
    const customError = {
      message: 'something went wrong'
    }
    throw customError
  }catch(error){
    console.log(error) 
    // put the error in  a variable  and display on the ui so the user know some error happened
  }
}
```